# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при подключении к голосовому каналу в лог-канал отправлялся embed c временем подключения

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
data = time.strftime('%x')
enter_time = time.strftime('%X')
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
    global enter_time
    global data
    global mess
    if after.channel != None:
        if after.channel.id == 817812456155381820:
            log_voice_channel = bot.get_channel(817800317856907314)
            emd = discord.Embed(title='Оповещение о подключении пользователя  к голосовому каналу',colour=0xd90000)
            emd.add_field(name='Пользователь:',value=member.mention)
            emd.add_field(name='Время подключения:',value=enter_time,inline=False)
            emd.add_field(name='Дата подключения:',value=data,inline=False)
            await log_voice_channel.send(embed = emd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо поместить переменные data и enter_time внутрь функции. У Вас получится:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after):
   data = time.strftime('%x')
   enter_time = time.strftime('%X')
   if after.channel != None:
       if after.channel.id == 817812456155381820:
           log_voice_channel = bot.get_channel(817800317856907314) 
           emd = discord.Embed(title='Оповещение о подключении пользователя  к голосовому каналу',colour=0xd90000)
           emd.add_field(name='Пользователь:',value=member.mention)
           emd.add_field(name='Время подключения:',value=enter_time,inline=False)
           emd.add_field(name='Дата подключения:',value=data,inline=False)
           await log_voice_channel.send(embed=emd)
```